# conservative vector fields - need a counterexample in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am given with the following statement:

1. If $\vec{F}(x,y)$ is conservative in a region $A$ and in a region $B$ , then it is also conservative in $A\cup B$ . I know the statement is incorrect, but will you please help me find an appropriate counterexample ?
2. If the vector field was in $\mathbb{R}^3 $, then the statement was correct?
3. I thought of taking the vector field $ \frac{1}{x^2+y^2} (-y,x) $ that is known to be conservative in any simply-connected domain in $\mathbb{R}^2 $ that does not contain the origin . So is an appropriate counter example can be two regions $A$ and $B$ that are simply connected and doesnot contain the origin, but their union is not simply connected?

Thanks a lot in advance everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sketch in (3) seems exactly right.

For example, you could let $A$ be an annulus with the northwest quadrant removed, and $B$ be the same annulus with the southeast quadrant removed.

You can extend the same example to 3 dimensions too, simply by ignoring the $z$ coordinate.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there any simple way to see that this field is not conservative if our domain of interest is not simply connected?

Comment: @dragonphoo: Easiest would be to make sure your annulus includes the unit circle and integrate one turn around that. You should gain $2\pi$ energy from the field for free.

Comment: (Of course there are _some_ non-simply-connected domains where the field _is_ conservative, such as an annulus placed such that the origin is _outside_ its outer perimeter).